# How I can start an action without clicking to a button?

Tags: ios, ios5, uikit, core-animation

I have two UIButtons and I want to click first in the Number1 `UIButton` and then in the Number 2 `UIButton`. After clicking the second `UIButton` I want the two `UIButton`'s to be rotated automatically. I use `CABasicAnimation` to rotate them. The two `UIButton`'s have the same `buttonClicked` action. The two buttons use different `CABasicAnimation` methods.

I have created a new method in order to rotate it, but when I call it from the `button clicked` action (same for the two buttons) only the first one is rotated. In order to call the rotate method I use `[self rotateButtons];`

The problem is that If I insert a new `UIButton` and give an `IBAction` to the new button it's fine. But I don't want a new button in the layer.

How I fix `rotateButtons` so that both buttons **could be rotated simultaneously**?

Here is the code:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    if ([value isEqualToString:@"SecondImage"])
    {
        UIImageView *myView2=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:numberOfCurrentButton+100];
        [myView2 setHidden:FALSE];
        UIImageView *myView=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:numberOfCurrentButton];
        [myView setHidden:TRUE];
        CALayer *layer2 =  myView2.layer;
        layer2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
        CABasicAnimation *animateImage2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"transform"];
        CATransform3D transform2 = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transform2.m34 = 1.0/-900.0; 
        self.view.layer.transform = transform2;
        layer2.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI/2, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        self.view.layer.transform = transform2;
        transform2 = CATransform3DRotate(transform2,  -M_PI, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        animateImage2.repeatCount = 1.0;
        animateImage2.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: transform2];
        animateImage2.duration = 0.5;
        animateImage2.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        animateImage2.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        [layer2 addAnimation: animateImage2 forKey: @"halfAnimatedImage"];

        return;
    }
}

-(void) rotateView1
{
    UIImageView *firstImage=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:numberOfCurrentButton];
    CALayer *layer =  firstImage.layer;
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
    CABasicAnimation *animateImage = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"transform"];
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = 1.0/-900.0; 
    self.view.layer.transform = transform;
    layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    [animateImage setDelegate:self ];
    animateImage.repeatCount = 0.5;
    animateImage.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: transform];
    animateImage.duration = 0.5;
    animateImage.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animateImage.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animateImage.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    [animateImage setValue:@"SecondImage" forKey:@"halfAnimatedImage"];
    [layer addAnimation: animateImage forKey: @"halfAnimatedImage"];
}
-(void) rotateView2
{
    UIImageView *firstImage=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:numberOfCurrentButton];
    CALayer *layer =  firstImage.layer;
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
    CABasicAnimation *animateImage = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"transform"];
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = 1.0/-900.0; 
    self.view.layer.transform = transform;
    layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    [animateImage setDelegate:self ];
    animateImage.repeatCount = 0.5;
    animateImage.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: transform];
    animateImage.duration = 0.5;
    animateImage.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animateImage.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animateImage.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    [animateImage setValue:@"SecondImage" forKey:@"halfAnimatedImage"];
    [layer addAnimation: animateImage forKey: @"halfAnimatedImage"];
}
-(IBAction) buttonRefresh:(UIButton *)sender
{
    numberOfCurrentButton=1; 
    [self rotateView1];
    numberOfCurrentButton=2;
    [self rotateView2];
}
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self buttonRefresh:sender];

}
```

`

Comment: You might want to include some code in your question to show what you've tried so far, and maybe some images to graphically describe what you're attempting to do?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I upload the code for the program. The action buttonClicked is for the two UIButtons. I want, when click on the second UIButton, the buttonRefresh action be started and rotate the two buttons.

Comment: Since rotateView1 and rotateView2 are identical, it would be easier to create a new `-(void)rotateViewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag {` method....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, your buttonClicked action receives the sender (the UIButton that was clicked) and you rotate the same.

To rotate both you could do either of the following:

1. Create an IBOutlet (not IBAction) for both the buttons. In your rotateButtons method, instead of just rotating the sender UIButton, rotate both these buttons.
2. As suggested by @lnafziger above, Tag both the buttons with numbers in the XIB. In the rotateButtons method rotate both this Buttons. You can get each UIButton by using the following code:

   ```
   UIbutton *button1 = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:101];
   ```

Comment: You understand my ploblem and I think your suggestion (number 1) with IBOutlet seems to be the best. I will try and I will tell you.